# postgresql: Finding the ids of rows that contain case-insensitive string duplication

Tags: sql, postgresql, case-insensitive, deduplication

I want to select and then delete a list of entries in my tables that have                                                                 case-insensitive duplications.

In other words, there are these rows that are unique... ..but they're not unique if you ignore case factor in case.  They got in while I wasn't watching.

So how can I select against the column to find the ids that I should delete?  (I'm fine with deleting both duplications).

simple sample column structure:

```
player_id | uname
------------------
34        | BOB
544       | bob
etc...
```

Comment: To be more specific, you don't want to "delete a list of entries" but rather, you want to keep exactly one of the entries, right?

Comment: Nah, I was okay with deleting none of the duplicates, just for ease of data-integrity, but keeping only one works fine as well.

Comment: ***meant was okay with deleting all of the duplicates, but yeah, whatever.  Moot point now.  *smiles*

Comment: Once you've cleaned up your data, I would recommend adding a "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_xyz ON table_abc (upper(uname)). This will prevent it from happening again plus it will give you an effective case-insensitive index if you use WHERE upper(uname) in a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Players to keep (assuming they registered first)

```
SELECT min(player_id) as player_id
FROM players
GROUP BY lower(uname)
```

Use it to dislay the users to remove and their corresponding keeper.

```
SELECT 
    players.player_id delete_id,
    players.uname delete_uname,
    keepers.uname keeper_uname,
    keepers.player_id keeper_id    
FROM players JOIN 
    (
        SELECT p.player_id, p.uname
        FROM players p JOIN
        (
            SELECT min(player_id) player_id
              FROM players
          GROUP BY lower(uname)
        ) as keeper_ids
        ON (p.player_id = keeper_ids.player_id)     
    ) as keepers
    ON (lower(players.uname) = lower(keepers.uname) AND players.player_id <> keepers.player_id)
ORDER BY keepers.player_id, players.player_id
```

Output:

```
delete_id | delete_uname | keeper_uname | keeper_id
---------------------------------------------------
544       | bob          | BOB          | 34
```

Comment: FYI: This SQL hasn't been tested.

Comment: Hmmm, that output works great... ...just not sure how to turn it into a deletion.

Comment: using the maximum player_id, I just used this a few times: delete from players where player_id in (SELECT max(player_id) as player_id
FROM players
GROUP BY lower(uname) having count(uname)>1);  Thanks for pointing it out, I should have seen it before.

Comment: Great! Keep in mind you may have more than 2 in mixed case. Bob BOB bob, this may affect the max logic.